# rounding up error in R with data type error

Tags: r

I know this is a very basic question. So you might wonder why this is even bothering. 
But, I have an issue with rounding numbers up.

I tried this but none of this worked.

```
mode(RNA_data) <- 'numeric'
```

> Error in mde(x) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

```
RNA_data<-as.numeric(RNA_data)
```

> > Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

```
round(P7_N02_RNA, digits=0)
```

> Error in Math.data.frame(list(P07_N02_RNA.genes.V5 = c(326L, 1L, 851L,  :
>   non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: P07_N02_RNA.genes.V5
>   Error: unexpected symbol in "non-numeric variable"

```
P7_N02_RNA <- round(P7_N02_RNA, digits=0)
```

> Error in Math.data.frame(list(P07_N02_RNA.genes.V5 = c(326L, 1L, 851L,  :
>   non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: P07_N02_RNA.genes.V5
>   Error: unexpected symbol in "non-numeric variable"

```
trimmed_RNA <- round(RNA_data$p07_N01,digit = 0)
```

> Error in round(RNA_data$p07_N01, digit = 0) :
>   non-numeric argument to mathematical function
>   Error: unexpected symbol in "non-numeric argument"

```
trimmed_RNA <- round(RNA_data[-1,], digits=0)
```

> Error in Math.data.frame(list(geneID = 2:58639, p07_N01 = c(2175L, 9753L,  : non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: geneID, p07_N01, p07_T01, p07_N02, p07_T02, p08_N01, p08_T01, p08_N02, p08_T02, p09_N01, p09_T01, p09_N02, p09_T02

```
RNA_data <-data.frame(RNA_data)
trimmed_RNA <- data.frame(round(as.numeric(levels(RNA_data)[RNA_data])))
```

> got a reault with 0 obs.

```
rm(trimmed_RNA)
require(data.table)
setDT(RNA_data)
RNA_data[, RNA_data:=round(as.numeric(levels(RNA_data)[RNA_data]))]
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(RNA_data, , `:=`(RNA_data, round(as.numeric(levels(RNA_data)[RNA_data])))) : RHS of assignment to existing column 'RNA_data' is zero length but not NULL. If you intend to delete the column use NULL. Otherwise, the RHS must have length > 0; e.g., NA_integer_. If you are trying to change the column type to be an empty list column then, as with all column type changes, provide a full length RHS vector such as vector('list',nrow(DT)); i.e., 'plonk' in the new column.**

This is how data looks like with 58639 rows.

[image]

I also tried to export files into csv file and trim them in excel but, also had a circular reference error, and didn't work. 
Now I have no idea what can I do.

Can anybody help me with rounding up those numbers?

Comment: Hi, I have tried to tidy up your question. Can you check that it is correct please. Also a screenshot of your data is not that useful; if you could edit your question with some of your actual data, for example `dput(yourdataframe[1:3, 1:10])`

Comment: ps have a look at `str(yourdataframe)` straight after data import. Check if the variables are the correct class i.e. are they factor / character rather than numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to tell from your question, but first convert your variables to numeric like this:

```
mtcars$mpg <- as.numeric( as.character( mtcars$mpg))
```

And is this what you mean by rounding up

```
ceiling( mtcars$qsec )
round( mtcars$disp , -1  )
```